# MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail change alert if returned no

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I use MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail in my app everything works great but if there are no accounts on the iPhone or iPad it returns a standard alertview what I would like to change. If I put a alert in the else it will return 2 alerts. Is there a way to change the standard alert it returns? Or at least change the text in it?

```
MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    controller.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"info@info.nl"];
    [controller setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    [controller setSubject:@"bericht van info"];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
}
else {

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try one thing.. Move your MFMailComposeViewController initialization code inside the `canSendMail` block.

Comment: brilliantly simple!

Answer (score 4):

Move the alloc of the 'MFMailComposeViewController' inside the if:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    controller.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"info@info.nl"];
    [controller setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    [controller setSubject:@"bericht van info"];
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];
} else {
    // Display custom alert here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the device can send emails with

`[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]`

And, if not, show the dialog in your side

Comment: I know its about the alertview it returns I would like to change. It returns a standard alertview with title:"No Mail Accounts" and message:"Please set up a Mail account in order to send email". I want to change this alert but I am not sure how. If I put a alertview in the else it just returns 1 more alertview.

Comment: That AlertView is shown by the controller. I'm not sure if you'll be able to change it. I think it is a best approach to try to guess if you can send mails or not.